# Mac OS app entitlements block internet connection

Tags: sandbox, xcode4.6, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I have a Mac OS app that needs outgoing connections.

I've followed Apple Code Signing Guide (Xcode 4.6.2) to enable entitlements and my target summary looks like this:

[image]

I have a MYAPP.entitlements file in my project that looks like:

[image]

Everything seems to be set in the right way, but when I try to run my app, even if

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

and

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

are called, nothing is loaded in my webView. Nor Little Snitch asks for connection.
Then, in Console no violation is presented.

If I try to change Entitlements setting, by unchecking "Allow Outgoing Connections", Console shows Sandbox violation this way:

```
20/05/13 00:44:09,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(908) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
20/05/13 00:44:10,593 sandboxd[908]: ([904]) MYAPP(904) deny mach-lookup com.apple.SystemConfiguration.SCNetworkReachability
20/05/13 00:44:10,601 sandboxd[908]: ([904]) MYAPP(904) deny system-socket
```

If I remove Enable App Sandboxing, everything works and my webView loads its contents...

I have tried:

1. to exit Xcode
2. to reboot my computer
3. to boot in save mode
4. to enable any combination of permissions in Entitlements
5. to create a new MYAPP.entitlements file
6. to rename my target

Anybody has experienced this behavior?
Any suggestion will be very appreciated... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up reinstalling my whole system and now it works...